# WPF: Detect when Window loses focus

Tags: wpf

How do I detect when my window loses focus?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use the [`Window.Deactivated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.deactivated.aspx).

You may be looking for the [`Application.Deactivated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.deactivated.aspx), which fires only if the user switched to a different application.

Comment: This worked great. I just wanted to clarify that it fires only if the user switched to a different _window_, regardless of whether or not that window is part of the same application.