# What property is set on the parent window when a child window is shown using showdialog()?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, showdialog

I have a custom window and would like to apply a custom style to the window when it cannot be accessed due to it having a child window (displayed via showdialog()). I assumed that the trigger property would be "IsEnabled", however this property is not set to false when showdialog() is called. I have also tried "Focusable" and looked through the list of properties in hope of finding the obvious solution. This led to me trying a data trigger which binds to "OwnedWindows.Count" but again this doesn't work! Surely this should be simple and I am missing something?

Triggers tried:

```
 <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">

 <Trigger Property="Focusable" Value="False">

 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OwnedWindows.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1" >
```

Note: Both IsEnabled and Focusable do the required job when I manually set the properties to *False* -  so I know the trigger works, they just aren't being set when ShowDialog() is called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: Detect when Window loses focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492732/wpf-detect-when-window-loses-focus)

Comment: @Steve - had my hopes up for a solution then - not the same issue, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property like that. Use [`ComponentDispatcher.EnterThreadModal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.enterthreadmodal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ComponentDispatcher.LeaveThreadModal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.leavethreadmodal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events instead. They are fired when a WPF modal dialog is shown or closed, respectively.

Comment: sorry, took me a while to come back to this issue! but you are absolutely correct! thanks