# Close Window on outside app click in WPF (Google Drive Tray App behavior)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I would like to reproduce the behavior of the Google Drive Tray App:

- Open a window on click on the tray icon (easy)
- Close the window on click outside of the tray icon and current window (?)

Most of the solutions I saw on internet rely on an equivalent of developing key-loggers, is it any other solution to perform this quite usual behavior?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492732/wpf-detect-when-window-loses-focus for possible help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to detect the focus of the window/app.

Refer to [WPF: Detect when Window loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492732/wpf-detect-when-window-loses-focus) for possible help.

Quote:

> Use the `Window.Deactivated` event. You may be looking for the `Application.Deactivated` event, which fires only if the user switched to a different application.