# C# detect pause of wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Using a medidaElement to play video and willing to pause it when its not active. So when the window is not active I want to fire the the mediaElement pause event.

How can I detect or register handler for such event?

I tried to add Deactivated window event handler but it's not defined and defining manually seems weird.

Comment: Please share the code you tried. Check this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/UseWindowActivatedandDeactivatedeventtocontrolamediafile.htm

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492732/wpf-detect-when-window-loses-focus

Comment: "it's not defined"? Of course it is.